# Putting in a basement bathroom and contractor hit/repaired foundation trench pipe?

Tags: plumbing, basement, pipe

We're putting in a basement bathroom and the contractor was digging to install the ejector pit/sump. He hit what I assume is a foundation pipe (each section is about 16", clay) that collects water and directs it to a sump in a different location. I assume this pipe is to collect and remove water under the home. I have a few questions for you experts:

1. As you can see, the repair made is a male connection instead of a female connection. Equates to what I estimate as a .5-inch difference. Won't this be concerning for gravity flow? Or am I overthinking, and the repair should be fine?
2. The new bathroom sump tank will be right below this area. Contractor is suggesting widening the hole the bathroom pipes access this tank. Claims oversized hole will help with the water table should levels rise. Should I tell them to seal the gap, fearing overstressing the pump?

[image: PIPE]

Comment: "was digging to install the ejector pit/sump" Is this a sanitary pump for bathroom grey water or a secondary sump for the foundation?

Answer (score 1):

They make furncos that attach 5" vitrified clay pipe to 4" pvc or abs.  They are expensive and would require more concrete exposed to install.

In the case of perimeter drains that are already made of clay and already have non-sealed connections and are typically installed flat to allow ground water to drain to a sump and prevent foundation wicking I'd accept this repair.